# Difference between TouchUtils.clickView() and Button.performClick() in Android Test?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-testing

I'm writing an integration test for my app using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, and I'm testing whether a button properly increments a counter in my UI.

The basic test just get the value shown in an TextView before and after the butotn click.

In one version I mark the test method with @UiThreadTest, and run the test like this

```
int value1;
int value2;
value1=(int) myText.getTheValue();
myButton.performClick();
value2=(int) myText.getTheValue();
assertEquals(value1 + 1, value2);
```

That all works fine, the test passes.

The second method, I don't us @UiThreadTest and instead perform the click using

```
TouchUtils.clickView(this, myButton);
```

In that case the assertion fails, because value1 equals value2.  I'm not sure whether that's because the OnClickListener didn't fire, the button wasn't pressed, or because the TouchUtils.clickView was running on the UI thread, and the test read the value of value2 before the handler incremented the textview's value. I tried Thread.sleep(1000) after the click to see if it just needed some time, but got the same result.

Can someone explain the proper way to use TouchUtils if you want to examine the impact of a click on on other UI elements of the Activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
            setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

    }
```

you need to keep your initial touch as false and then use 
    TouchUtils.clickView()

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not the problem.  I do call setActivitiyInitialTouchMode(false) in the setup procedure.

Answer (score -1):

i;ve got two points for you here.

and also make sure clickView has two parameters
    clickView( reference to the test case that is being run,a reference to the Button to manipulate.)

Note: The TouchUtils helper class provides convenience methods for simulating touch interactions with your application. You can use these methods to simulate clicking, tapping, and dragging of Views or the application screen.

Caution: The TouchUtils methods are designed to send events to the UI thread safely from the test thread. You should not run TouchUtils directly in the UI thread or any test method annotated with @UIThread. Doing so might raise the WrongThreadException.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, and suggest solutions that have already been tried as evident from the code snippet above.